# How to dynamically change language in Hexo?

Tags: hexo

I only found there is config file to set the language.
But I want user could select it and change dynamically.
Just like Hexo home page did https://hexo.io/docs/internationalization.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be helpful: https://hexo.io/docs/permalinks.html#Multi-language-Support

first, edit `_config.yml` and setting `new_post_name` and `permalink`.

```
new_post_name: :lang/:title.md
permalink: :lang/:title/
```

then, create a new post should save as this:

```
hexo new "Hello World" --lang tw
```

finally, when you traverse each post to show them, you can use `post.lang` to decide show it or not.

```
<% page.posts.each(function(post) { %>
  <% if (post.lang === ('tw')) { %>
    <%- partial('_partial/article') %>
  <% } %>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Good to see hexo completed this feature. :D

Comment: @Jiu Hope you enjoy this~